# yoloV8: how I can to predict and save the image with boxes on the objects with pytorch

Tags: pytorch, yolo

```
import torch
import glob
import os
import pathlib
from ultralytics import YOLO

model_name='MyBest.pt'
model = torch.hub.load(<?>, 'custom', source='local', path = model_name, force_reload = True)
results = model(person.png)  # predict on an image
results.save()
```

What should I write instead: <?>

I'm trying to get an image with BOX on all objects I want the code to use both yoloV8 and pytorch

Answer (score 3):

According to the official [python usage source](https://docs.ultralytics.com/python/), release 8.0.20:

```py
from ultralytics.yolo.engine.model import YOLO

model = YOLO("yolov8s.pt")
results = model.predict(source='ultralytics/assets', save=True, save_txt=True)
```

Comment: thanks. but I try to use the model and save with boxes on the objects

Comment: updated comment! this saves both images with predictions and bboxes

Answer (score 0):

You can use these codes for more details:

```
for result in results:
   boxes = result.boxes  # Boxes object for bbox outputs
   masks = result.masks  # Masks object for segmenation masks outputs
   probs = result.probs  # Class probabilities
   print(boxes)
   print(masks)
   print(probs)


boxes = results[0].boxes
box = boxes[0]  # returns one box
box.xyxy
boxes.xyxy  # box with xyxy format, (N, 4)
boxes.xywh  # box with xywh format, (N, 4)
boxes.xyxyn  # box with xyxy format but normalized, (N, 4)
boxes.xywhn  # box with xywh format but normalized, (N, 4)
boxes.conf  # confidence score, (N, 1)
boxes.cls  # cls, (N, 1)
boxes.data  # raw bboxes tensor, (N, 6) or boxes.boxes .
```

You can go to the docs.ultralytics page for more information
https://docs.ultralytics.com/predict/